# What thread to use for Cordova plugin callback?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

In what thread are the methods of [`CallbackContext`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CallbackContext.java) supposed to be called?

The documentation for `CordovaPlugin#execute(...)` says it's called in the WebView thread.  Is that the same as the UI thread?  If so, then that's probably my answer.

If the WebView thread is not the UI thread, and I'm supposed to call back in the WebView thread, is it possible to do so asynchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I put you the Threading section of the android plugins documentation.
The plugins are all asynch, when you call them you get a success or failure callback. The theads are just to not block the UI if the native task is too long.

> Threading
>
> The plugin's JavaScript does not run in the main thread of the WebView
>   interface; instead, it runs on the WebCore thread, as does the execute
>   method. If you need to interact with the user interface, you should
>   use the following variation:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Use the following if you do not need to run on the main interface's
>   thread, but do not want to block the WebCore thread either:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Note from Kevin:

Calls to the methods of `CallbackContext` end up calling `CordovaWebView#sendPluginResult(PluginResult cr, String callbackId)`. The implementation of that method in `CordovaWebViewImpl` calls `NativeToJsMessageQueue#addPluginResult(cr, callbackId)`, which ultimately results in an element being added to a `LinkedList` inside a synchronized block. All accesses to that `List` are synchronized

Comment: These examples contradict each other.  One calls the callback in the UI thread, the other calls it in a worker thread.  Are you really telling me that there is no convention for what thread the callback occurs in?  Typically it would be more than a convention; it would be a guarantee specified by the contract of `execute(...)`.

Comment: No, there are 3 ways to call execute. The "normal" way executes the callbackContext in the WebCore thread. But you can execute the callbackContext on the UI thread (first example) or another thread different from WebCore and UI thread (second example). All of them are async. You can choose whichever you need, if you don't mind blocking the UI then use the regular way, if you don't want to block it, use the UI thread, if the code you want to execute can't be run on the UI thread then use the second example.

Comment: It looks like you're right about it being okay to call the callback in a random worker thread.  Here's why.  Could you add this to your answer?

Calls to the methods of `CallbackContext` end up calling `CordovaWebView#sendPluginResult(PluginResult cr, String callbackId)`.  The implementation of that method in `CordovaWebViewImpl` calls `NativeToJsMessageQueue#addPluginResult(cr, callbackId)`, which ultimately results in an element being added to a `LinkedList` inside a `synchronized` block.  All accesses to that `List` are synchronized (except one - I'll submit a bug.)

Comment: I have added your comment to the answer

Comment: Can you clarify this note? Does this mean that ultimately `callbackContext.success()` is always thread-safe and will run on the UI thread?

Comment: I think it only means that it's synchronized, but not on the UI thread, if you want to run the code on the UI thread use `runOnUiThread`. Anyway, the `callbackContext.success();` usually doesn't takes a lot of time to run (unless you return a big value), the code you have to worry about blocking the UI is the rest of the code that your plugin executes.