# How can I programmatically replace the window view to a XAML page in a WinJS app?

Tags: windows, cordova, xaml, uwp, winjs

I have a cordova application that has a plugin that uses OpenGL/DirectX that needs to take over the app window. I have everything working great, up until I go to actually set the contents of the app window. When I go to instantiate the XAML page I get an error about not being on the correct thread:

> RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

I've seen a few people say this isn't possible, but I feel like it has to be possible in someway, unless the window is sandboxed or something. I'm also thinking the problem may be that the XAML backend service/framework/whatever isn't setup in a WinJS app? In which case is there some way to manually set it up?

I'd appreciate any help at all, and at least an explanation as to why it's not possible. I'm pretty new to Windows programming and I appreciate knowing why something can't be done.

Thanks!

P.S.

I've also tried to run the code that creates the XAML class inside of a dispatcher:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync
```

Here is my code:

```
void MyComponent::doStuff(){
    if (m_directXPage == nullptr)
    {
        try
        {
            m_directXPage = ref new DirectXPage();
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            e.what();
        }

    }

    // Place the page in the current window and ensure that it is active.
    Window::Current->Content = m_directXPage;
    Window::Current->Activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I go to instantiate the XAML page I get an error about not being on the correct thread.

Cordova executes plugins asynchronously. Please see [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978547/what-thread-to-use-for-cordova-plugin-callback). So the native codes, consumed by the OpenGL/DirectX plugin don't have access to your UI thread.

Currently there is no other approach to load XAML targeting windows platform.

Comment: @Kyle you are right, forgot that, sorry. I've updated the answer. Currently there is no other approach to load XAML targeting windows.